# Interface IP details mentioned in /etc/network/interfaces file but restarting server makes interfaces assigned some random IP

Tags: debian, networking, ip, networkmanager

While trying to set eth3 with static ip, below are my actions and Observations.

**Actions 1**

Step1) Edited the /etc/network/interfaces file and below is the content

```
#This file describes the network interfaces available on your system and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5)

#The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#manual ip set for eth3
auto eth3
allow-hotplug eth3
iface eth3 inet static
address x.x.x.x
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Step 2)Ran systemctl restart networking.service

Step 3)Restart server

**Observation 1**

x.x.x.x ip is getting set in eth2 & eth3 is getting set to random ip And then if I restart networking.service, eth3 is also getting set to x.x.x.x ip as defined in /etc/network/interfaces file So 2 different interfaces are getting set to same ip

**Actions 2**

Step 1) Now removed NetworkManager folder present in /etc/ Step 2)restart server

**Observation 2**

eth3 is still assigned with a random ip other than x.x.x.x & no ip is assigned in eth2 now. When I restart networking.service now, eth3 is getting assigned with x.x.x.x ip as defined in /etc/network/interfaces file and eth2 doesn’t have any IP address assigned.

So when i restart the server, it is taking ip values from other reference and after restarting network.service, it is taking values as given in /etc/network/interfaces file.

**How can i restrict random ip getting assigned to the interface which is defined static in interfaces file?**

Comment: What system are you using? What is the "random" IP? check the syslog, look for that random IP and eth2 and eth3.

Comment: When you "restart server", what do you do? Turn off the computer and back on, or you give a command to re-start some server software (Apache maybe) ?

Comment: Have you tried with `ifdown -a; ifup -a` to restart the network ?

Comment: @gabor.zed I am using debain 11 and random ip means taking from network other than the ip defined in /etc/network/interfaces file

Comment: @QuartzCristal i am using init 6 command to restart the VM. Also I will try using ifdown -a; ifup -a

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion and explanation:

Linux years ago have started to develop solution to old slow script based services management. The "systemd" faster smarter allowing for parallel service startup .... In short **improved** started to replace old script based systems. **Today in Debian 11 the networking system is "systemd-networkd". The old scripts for network configuration are translated to systend-networkd.** Development of systemd and updating translators have went out of sink in past. To avoid translation problems I suggest to drop using old configurations and start using new systemd based configuration directly.

Steps to fix your networ:

**1)** Check status of your network configuration using:

```
networkctl -a status
```

**2)** Remove configuration for old ifupdown system by renaming it:

```
mv /etc/network/interfaces  /etc/network/interfaces.save
```

**3)** Enable new systemd configuration:

```
systemctl enable systemd-networkd
```

**4)** Create new configuration files for systemd-networkd:

```
/etc/systemd/network/1-eth1.network
/etc/systemd/network/1-eth3.network
```

The syntax for systemd-networkd is different then in interfaces. Example:

```
[Match]
Name=eth3

[Network]
Address=x.x.x.x/24
```

Now reboot the server and check if eth3 is as expected. You my need to create configuration for other networks in your system. Start reading about systemd-networkd configuration syntax.

https://manpages.debian.org/testing/systemd/systemd.network.5.en.html

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd-networkd